# Does python's recvfrom() queue packets?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, listener, recv

My impression was recvfrom() gave you the next packet on the IP and port it is listening on, and if it is not listening packets get missed.  We are having an issue where the problem could be packets are queued up for recvfrom(), therefore it is listening and catching all packets even when recvfrom() is not actively listening.

I could not find definitive documentation on this.  Does anybody know for sure the characteristics of recvfrom() is to not queue packets when not being called?

code example:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

mcast_g = socket.inet_aton(group)
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', mcast_g, socket.INADDR_ANY)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

s.bind(('', port))

while True:
    data, sender = s.recvfrom(1500)
    # Do stuff
    # Are packets being queued up here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a socket receive buffer in the kernel. `recv()` and friends read from the buffer, or block while it's empty. If you don't read fast enough, the buffer fills, and UDP datagrams that arrive when the buffer is full are dropped. You can vary the size of the buffer with the socket option `SO_RCVBUFSIZE.`

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the OS implementation but there is an amount of buffering present on most modern OSs.

Comment: So what your saying is the OS's IP stack queuing a message is completely separate from the actions of recvfrom().  If the OS is queuing messages then recvfrom() doesn't care.  It just takes the next message from the stack.

Comment: `recvfrom()` is *part* of the OS.  It doesn't make sense to try to talk about them as two non-cooperating entities like this.  If the OS has a buffer (and basically all of them do), then that buffer is where `recvfrom()` is taking data from.

Comment: I don't see where Steve said anything of the sort actually. I'd caution you against the habit of "so you're saying". The result is invariably a mistake.